# Human directed search

Tags: search, machine-learning, pattern-matching, artificial-intelligence, bayesian

For all the machine-learning folks.

What I'm wondering is how to search high dimensional data with the help of input in the form of user preference/clicks.

Suppose I have a program that generates images from feature vectors. The program takes a random sample of N vectors, generates their corresponding images, and displays the images in a grid on a computer screen. Next, a user clicks on the image he thinks is "best" (out of the N images displaying, and according to some given criteria). The program now generates another sample of images, displays these to the user, and repeats the process.

Given a system like this, what algorithms would you employ to find the "best" feature vector (and corresponding image)... In the case I'm working on, the feature vectors are binary valued of length 512, and the grid is 3x3 (9 vectors picked at each iteration). Also, the user preference, or "best", is a very subjective measurement.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's my current method:**

Basically, what I'm currently doing is building a [Naive Bayes Classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier/) (it might look complex in writing, but it's rather simple to implement). For each possible state of each feature (512 features * 2 states = 1024), I assign a [Beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) prior, which estimates the probability that this particular feature state will result in a user "click". When a user clicks an image, I update my priors.

Now the question is, how do I generate a new list of 9 sample vectors to display to the user? Well, I realized this is a [Multi-Armed Bandit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit) problem. For that, [Thompson Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_sampling) is an easy to use method. For each vector, and for each feature, I pick a state (either 0 or 1) with probability p, where p is proportional to the probability that the chosen state is the best (i.e., results in maximum likelihood for my Naive Bayes Classifier). To do this, I just sample from the Beta distribution for that feature at state 0, and also for that feature at state 1. I then set the feature depending on which sample is greatest.

This works to some degree.

**BIG Caveat:**

The main issue with what I'm doing is I am assuming independence in my features. More than that, and partly because the features are *not* independent, the distributions change as I iterate through this (partially invalidating previous data). Finally, the way I'm using Thompson sampling might not be best.

**Where now?**

My big question is, once I have a Naive Bayes classifier, how do I remove the assumption of independence? And with this updated model, can I still do something like Thompson sampling?

**Exploration vs Exploitation**

Thompson sampling helps to balance exploration vs exploitation. But since I have 9 images to choose from, surely some of those can be more exploitative. Here's one idea I had to keep my current model, but make it more exploitative. If we know the probability of a feature being set (based on Thompson sampling), we can make the algorithm more exploitative by weighting that probability exponentially. I.e.: Pnew = p^w / (p^w + (1-p)^w)... Since I'm displaying 9 images, I could perhaps choose w=[1..9]... We have to estimate p (the probablitiy of one beta random variable greater than another). For that, I can use moment matching to estimate normal distributions, and determine the probability from that. This is described [Here - in CrossValidated StackExchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53304/analytical-approximation-of-probability-of-one-beta-distributed-var-being-greate). To further enhance this, I might keep the selected image from the previous iteration (giving only 8 new images).

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem space is huge and the size of the training set is small (as kudkudak also states) I think you need to emphesise on exploiting the knowledge found so far. Thomson sampling will balance exploration with exploitation, but I fear you would need to many iterations to make it work.

Instead of Thomson sampling, you could try to flip n random bits of the selected vector, then flip n-1 bits next round etc. That would be a very greedy algorithm that most likely end up in a local minima, but aiming for anything else seems far fetched (I think).

There are clear similarities with genetic algorithms in this problem, where crossover and mutation have the exploration/exploitation role. You might find some inspiration there.

Comment: Yes, I've realized that genetic algorithms might be a solution. For example, I found this: http://www.jhlabs.com/java/art.html  (generating art with a GA).

Comment: I made an edit to my answer as a possible mechanism to make my model more exploitative.

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand correctly your question. I am seeing here 2 interpretations of your question, or you are trying to find the best feature vector (image) in every 3x3 grid, or from all of the images. I will try to propose something working in both cases.

It seems to be hard due to high dimensionality, and probably small training set. It would be much easier to work with smaller vectors, you can try applying a dimensionality reduction algorithm (like PCA, autoencoders).

One approach I though of is doing ELO rating, even if this is not the ultimate answer, you can always use it (for instance as another entry of feature vector).

I would firstly reduce the dimensionality if it is possible. Then transform user clicks to training set of the form `(v_1, v_2), y`, where y indicates the v_1 image or v_2 image was better (so it is 1 or 0). Then we can try to train a classifier for that. It assumes that in every 3x3 the best feature vector wins, and other examples do not affect decision which is only done "pairwisely", which is quite sensible.

To find the best we can compare all `n^2` pairs and see which feature vectore scores best. For perfectly learned model there should be one better than every other (transitive relation).

---

Another idea is to a train neural network model, that would assign real number to every feature vector. Now for each training example (choice of the best among 3x3) we can get 8 comparisions, and see if the predicted "score" for feature vector is conforming with the user's preference. For the training error : naively we can ask neural network to make them differ only by one. Or we can leverage ELO and weight the difference by the difference in ELO. This uses knowledge from the whole training set and should get better results

Comment: My question is: I have feature vectors of length 512 (so 2^512 possibilities). Each generates an image. I randomly select 9 feature vectors, and display the resulting images to a user. User clicks an image he thinks is "best". I then generate 9 more vectors, hoping to get closer to the user's preference out of all 2^512 possibilities.

Comment: I like your idea about ELO rating. It's interesting. I may be able to incorporate that into my Naive Bayes classifier. I like it because it helps to deal with the fact that the distribution of which images are displayed to the user changes, and become "better" (invalidating old data).

Comment: See below for my current method.

Comment: Right, this is quite different question. I will nevertheless leave my answer, maybe it will be useful. Your method is very clever, but it inherently treats features as independent and I do not have any clear idea how to modify it to get rid of this assumption for now.